# deleted local migration file before pushing to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, migration

I've somehow managed to delete a local migration file before I pushed to heroku.  I have migrated the change locally so all works fine on my machine, but when checking the table on heroku I can see that a specific column is missing.

I've tried adding the migration directly on heroku by running:

`heroku run rails g migration AddRoasterIdToRoasts roaster_id:integer` and then `heroku run rails db:migrate`, but as of yet I can't see that that has updated my table on heroku.

Any other ideas?

Comment: What version control system do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate locally a new migration, change it's name to move it in right place among other migrations (I mean change timestamp), commit the migration and then just deploy the project to Heroku.

Comment: what time stamp would it need to be?  I have lost track of when I would have done this compared to other migrations around it.

Comment: It's up to you. If you don't have any migration that depend on `roaster_id` column on `roast` table you can even don't change the timestamp and just leave the created migration the newest.

Comment: Bingo!  Luckily it worked just with the current timestamp.